# HQL query select one set of columns vs select other columns when a particular column is null

Tags: hql

What I want to accomplish is the following.  Please let me know how I can combine these two cases into one HQL conditional query.
If myID is not null then use this query

```
@Query("select item from Item where a = ?1 and b=?2 and c=?3 and myID=?4)
```

If If myID is null then use this query

```
@Query("select item from Item where a = ?1 and b=?2 and c=?3)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there a way to handle this in HQL directly or I should look into using Criteria API for handle this case where one input parameter can be null.